# What's the purpose for link-local address?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip

Anyone has the clear idea what the link-local address for. ie. 169.254.*.*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [RFC 5735 - Special Use IPv4 Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735)...

> 169.254.0.0/16 - This is the "link local" block.  As described in
> [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927), it is allocated for communication
> between hosts on a single link.  Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration,
> such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.